# Node not joining galera cluster after reboot

Tags: galera

I have upgraded from Debian 10 to 11 on one of the nodes of a Galera cluster. The other nodes complain on Icinga that node 1 is disconnected from them and is not synced...I rebooted after the upgrade to see if it would join back and it didn't but the server was up and running. Can someone help me with what to do to get this node back to the cluster?

Thanks

wsrep | 0 |

wsrep_applier_thread_count | 0 |

wsrep_cluster_capabilities | |

wsrep_cluster_conf_id | 18446744073709551615 | |

wsrep_cluster_size | 0 |

wsrep_cluster_state_uuid | |

wsrep_cluster_status | Disconnected | |

wsrep_connected | OFF | |

wsrep_local_bf_aborts | 0 | |

wsrep_local_index | 18446744073709551615 | |

wsrep_provider_capabilities | |

wsrep_provider_name | |

wsrep_provider_version | |

| wsrep_ready | OFF | |

wsrep_rollbacker_thread_count | 0 |

| wsrep_thread_count | 0 –

Comment: I think you need to provide a lot more details before anyone is able to help. For example: 1) Which version of MariaDB is installed on each node? 2) Is the MariaDB server instance running on node 1? 3) Can you share any useful-looking info from your MariaDB error file? 4) If the MariaDB server instance is running on node 1, what is the result of `mysql -e "show status where variable_name in ('wsrep_ready', 'wsrep_local_state_comment', 'wsrep_connected', 'wsrep_cluster_size');"` If the instance is not running on node 1, then please run the command on another node.

Comment: 10.6.8-MariaDB-1:10.6.8+maria~buster mariadb.org binary                                               wsrep_ready                   | ON                                                                  wsrep_cluster_size            | 4                                                                                  wsrep_connected               | ON                                                                                      wsrep_local_state_comment     | Synced

Comment: And is that the result from node 1? How many nodes do you have in the cluster? Did the MariaDB version stay the same when you upgraded Debian?

Comment: Yes its from node 1 and we have 4 nodes in the cluster. Yes the version also remains same after upgrade.

Comment: In that case it looks like it's fine. The `show status` command shows that the node is in fact joined and synced. Maybe it's just a hiccup with the way Icinga is determining whether a node is connected? (How does Icinga connect to the node?) You can also find the MariaDB error file (it's typically in the datadir (by default `/var/lib/mysql/`) or in a dir like `/var/log/mysql/` or `/var/log/mariadb/`) and then look for issues in that file. Although it really sounds like it's working fine.

Comment: What if in case it says not synced with other nodes. What should i do in that case. Is there any specific command that needs to run to let a node join others. As yesterday I did another node upgarde and it showed that its not sync with other nodes and ofcourse not joined so i had to revert back to the previous state.

Comment: @dbdemon can you please help with this.

Comment: No, there is no command you need to run beyond just starting the mariadb service. Do you mean to say that the `show status ...` command shows 'not synced'? It may just be a simple matter of waiting long enough until it is in fact synced. This can take a while for a big database if it has to do a full SST. You can use Linux shell commands such as `ps -ef f` to see whether your expected SST method is running on the joiner node and on whichever node is automatically chosen as the donor.

Comment: Hi dbdemon.....the node didn't join but mariadb version changed from 10.6.8 to 10.6.9

Comment: added the status of the node in the link

Comment: To help other users, please update your question with all the info/answers you have given in the comments. Also, did the MariaDB configuration files get modified when you upgraded Debian? That would explain the 'wsrep%' status variables you have shown. It looks like you now have a configuration on this node without values for the Galera / wsrep system variables.

Comment: Hi dbdemon......after i ran puppet agent -t on the node....i can now see all the config files and node is joined and synced to the other nodes but now i see on all nodes with this error on icinga and also the galera01 node is updated with mariadb 10.6.8 to 10.6.9   Node state : synced , Cluster members (4) ,                                                                          !! disconnected nodes: galera 01.gk !!                                                                              
!! cluster should contain an odd number of nodes !!